# Como puedo lograr installar react en node js no me deja?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

```bash
C:\Users\UCI>npx create-react-app miapp

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network
---
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\UCI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-03T10_02_33_677Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Intenta abrir esa url con el navegador desde el dispositivo donde estes intentando instalar react: `https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app` a ver que te dice y si llegas a ella. Parece que no puedes por los motivos que sean.

Comment: ya la intente me actualice a una version de node js nueva tambien quite los firewall pero nada